# Ensure all the bytes are properly written to file

Tags: c++, qt, read-write, qfile

Is it possible to check if all the bytes are actually being written on a QFile or not? Currently this is all I have

```
QFile f(name);
if (f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
     f.write(bytes);
}
```

`bytes` has a size of 1MB and there are times when the entire chunk is not written to file, hence I end up getting a corrupted file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) with which you can check the integrity of your data. What you want to do here is use [qChecksum](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#qChecksum) like this:

```
QFile f(name);
if (f.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
     f.write(bytes);
}

quint16 fileCheckSum = qChecksum(bytes.data(), bytes.length());

if (f.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    QByteArray writtenBytes = f.readAll();

    quint16 writtenBytesCheckSum = qChecksum(writtenBytes .data(), writtenBytes .length());

    if(fileCheckSum == writtenBytesCheckSum)
    {
        qDebug() << "File is valid.";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "File is corrupt.";
    }
}
```

I haven't compiled the code but it should work. If it doesn't I'll be more specific with an example.

Comment: Of course this doesn't ensure that the file actually made it to the disk, since you're checksumming the cache, and it doesn't ensure that in case the write was to fail, the original file wouldn't be destroyed.

Answer (score 9):

In Qt 5 you really should be using [`QSaveFile`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsavefile.html). It ensures two very important invariants:

1. partial/failed writes don't corrupt the existing file,
2. the file is flushed by the time the `QSaveFile` instance is destructed.

Since this is a proper C++ class, implementing RAII, you don't need to do anything special to ensure that it works, except for having to call `commit()`. The meaning of `commit()` is: you indicate that you will *not* be writing any more data to the file. At this point, the implementation is free to close the file, flush it to disk, and replace the old file with the new one.

```
/// When this function returns true, you can be certain that the file contains exactly "foo bar".
bool writeFooBar() {
  QSaveFile file(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation));
  if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return false;
  if (-1 == file.write("foo bar"))
    return false;
  return file.commit();
}
```

Comment: Does this work on an Android tablet and there are high possibility of power failure ?

Comment: I presume it would, it's Linux and I presume that Qt uses the usual Linux C library to access the filesystem.

Answer (score 5):

If you're worried about corrupted files being written, perhaps [QSaveFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsavefile.html) would be a better class to use, instead of QFile.

As the documentation states: -

> *QSaveFile is an I/O device for writing text and binary files, without losing existing data if the writing operation fails.*

Answer (score 2):

To *ensure* that all the bytes are written *properly* to a file, you should maintain a digest (checksum) of all the bytes written to the file.  Compare the result of the result of the running checksum to that of a checksum performed over the file.

Please research SHA-1 (Secure Hash Algorithm), MD5 and "Hash functions".  Also "c++ data integrity algorithm".

Comment: Maybe it helps for OP. Qt already has some class for md5 and other: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QCryptographicHash.html

Comment: Thanks for the link @Chernobyl. I am getting the SHA1 for each `bytes` at the moment. I am just not too familiar with the process @ThomasMatthews is talking about. I guess I will need to research further and get back to it.

Answer (score 1):

QFile::flush or QFile::close should cause all buffered contents to be written. It's important to check the return values of all of the QFile calls.

Comment: In my application, I am writing multiple `bytes` of 1MB each. Say after adding 10 MB of data, if I do `f.flush()` I would know that a certain block was incomplete? Will I be able to figure out which block specifically though?

Comment: write, flush or close will return false if the lower level system call fails. For example, if there is no more disk space. If you don't trust that, maybe because another process or thread is scribbling on your file, you could close the file, open it read-only and compare to bytes. What if the file becomes corrupt after that test? At some point you have to trust the return values.